# Por que "arroba" (@)?

Tags: etimologia, origem

Fora unidade de medida, "arroba" pode significar o símbolo @, utilizado na internet.

O inglês chama de *at* com o sentido de *em*, por exemplo `vinicius em gmail.com`. Assim faz também a língua árabe, hindi, curda, lituana, etc.

Porém, no nosso português e também no espanhol, diz-se "arroba". Por que demos esse nome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Porém, no nosso português e também no espanhol, diz-se "arroba". Por que demos esse nome?

Esse é o nome histórico do @. Esse símbolo é usado com o significado de arroba desde pelo menos [o século XVI](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2000/jul/31/internetnews.internationalnews) no sul da Europa, e a unidade de medida é usada ainda hoje para alguns produtos agrícolas no Brasil e alguns países da América do Sul.

Isso significa que provavelmente uma porção grande o bastante dos falantes já associava o nome "arroba" ao @ quando do início do seu uso na internet, e ele simplesmente se manteve (especialmente com sua aparência não lembrando o significado de "em"). Em inglês, o símbolo já era em parte chamado de "*at*", embora no sentido comercial de "a", ou "por unidade" -- como em "10 maçãs, @ $2 (cada)".

Enquanto os falantes de inglês mantiveram o nome histórico "*at*" (embora com um novo significado, "em" ao invés de "a"), e em português e espanhol mantivemos o nome histórico (apenas como um nome), países que não usavam o símbolo ainda parecem ter se dividido entre: 1) ler o "@" de acordo com o significado moderno mais comum, "em"; e 2) de acordo [com sua aparência](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-35744456): "macaco-aranha", em alemão; "rosa", em turco; "rabo de porco", em norueguês; "patinho", em grego; "minhoca", em húngaro...

Comment: +1. Em adição, os alemães chamam de _Klammeraffe_ (macaco-aranha) por conta da semelhança com o rabo dos animais. Seria muito estranho chamarmos de coisas assim na língua portuguesa 

Comment: @ViniBrasil Claro! Como pude me esquecer. Obrigado, já adicionei.

Comment: Já ouvi há muitos anos e repetidamente de diversas pessoas profissionais de informática nos anos 80s e 90s: "A-cobrinha" e "rabo de macaco". Nunca mais ouvi. O mesmo ocorreria para infinitos nomes para o "#".

Comment: Verdade, @Luciano, não é porque um dado termo se estabeleceu, que ele sempre tenha sido o mais usado. Pessoalmente, nas raras vezes que ouvia alguém usar um nome alternativo para o arroba, sempre atribuía a brincadeira ou a desconhecimento, similar ao "chapéu" para o acento "circunflexo".

Answer (score 1):

Usava-se o símbolo **@** com o significado de *arroba* quando ainda usava tal [unidade de medida](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arroba).

Aliás, se quisermos ler o símbolo como *a* seguindo o modelo de outras línguas, seria muito confuso por não se diferenciar com a letra A que é muito frequente nos endereços.

Comment: Outras línguas leem o símbolo como "a"?

Comment: O inglês por exemplo. A palavra inglesa *at* traduz-se normalmente *a* no português. Mesmo se usarmos *em*, seria difícil as vezes distinguir da letra E (ou, no caso do castelhano, com N)

Comment: guifa e @Vini, neste contexto, ***a*** não faria qualquer sentido. "jacinto@gmail" nunca seria "jacinto a gmail"; poderia ser "jacinto **em** gmail", tal como "Jacinto is at home" se traduz por "Jacinto está em casa". Se nós lêssemos o @ como "em", creio que qualquer falante nativo identificaria o "em" sem o confundir com uma letra **e**.